# Join table using the numeric value of an alphanumeric string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I have to join table a and table b

The joining column:

```
table a has a column named: usr_sq_num which is a bigint
table b has a column named: created_by which is varchar(100)
```

usr_sq_num contains only digits like 8574, 6732, 8957
created_by contains values like: USER8574, USER6732, USER8957

This is the only column I can join table a with table be.

how can I grab the numeric portion of a string such as "USER8574" and join to a value such as 8574?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is obviously a data model issue, so you (or somebody) should fix it. Either make it an integer or make it 'USERnnnn' in both tables.

Comment: Just be aware that this is a terrible design for performance and data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

If the prefix is the same, you can use:

```
on concat('USER', t1.usr_sq_num) = t2.created_by
```

Or, you could use `like` if the prefix is not known:

```
on t2.created_by like concat('%[^0-9]', t1.usr_sq_num)
```

Comment: this part on concat('USER', t1.usr_sq_num) = t2.created_by gives me the part USER, when I put in in a SELECT. Shouldn't I be getting the numeric part instead? Thank you.

Comment: @erasmocarlos . . . I don't understand your comment.  This is the `on` clause for the `JOIN` which is what you are asking about.